# xargs docker stop needs at least 1 argument in GitLab CI job

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I have a GitLab CI/CD YAML pipeline file with some jobs, the last stage has this code:

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - chmod 400 $SSH_KEY
  script:
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $SSH_KEY root@161.35.223.117 "
        docker login -u $REGISTRY_USER -p $REGISTRY_PASS &&
        docker ps -aq | xargs docker stop | xargs docker rm && #BUG HERE!
        docker run -d -p 5000:5000 $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG"
```

`xargs docker stop` gives error

```
Login Succeeded
"docker stop" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker stop --help'.
Usage:  docker stop [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]
Stop one or more running containers
unknown shorthand flag: 'd' in -d
See 'docker rm --help'.
```

How to deal with it? I tried without `xargs`:

```
docker login -u $REGISTRY_USER -p $REGISTRY_PASS &&
docker stop $(docker ps -aq) | xargs docker rm &&
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG"
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this without the need of `xargs`:

```bash
  script:
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i "$SSH_KEY" root@161.35.223.117 "
        docker login -u $REGISTRY_USER -p $REGISTRY_PASS || exit;
        docker stop \$(docker ps -aq) || exit;
        docker rm \$(docker ps -aq) || exit;
        docker run -d -p 5000:5000 $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG"
```

Comment: Do we know `docker ps -aq` will have any output? If it doesn't, why wouldn't we get the same "requires at least 1 argument" error the OP already had?

Comment: what is slash in docker stop?

Comment: @ERJAN, the backslash defers the `$(...)` so the `docker ps` runs on the remote machine not the local machine.

Comment: (BTW, the quoting here is buggy; ideally, we'd want `-i "$SSH_KEY"`; inside the double quotes it's trickier -- if the local shell is bash 5.0 or later, then `${REGISTRY_USER@Q}`, `${REGISTRY_PASS@Q}`, &c are the obvious answer, but you need to force specifically bash, not sh, for that)

Comment: I'd also consider replacing `foo && bar && baz` with `foo || exit; bar || exit; baz` -- that way if you want a failure from `bar` to _not_ cause everything else to fail, you can just leave off the `|| exit` for that one command; it's trickier with a chain, because making it `foo && bar; baz` will make `baz` run even if `foo` fails.

Comment: I will address all the comments to improve the answer. Yes, quoting is buggy, I just cared about the relevant parts that were modified (docker stop; docker rm). `foo || exit; bar || exit; baz` could be simplified to `set -e; foo; bar; baz`, right?

Comment: @SebastianLiebscher, `set -e` is [deeply problematic](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) (skip the story and go to the examples if in a hurry); its behavior differs in surprising ways based on context (like whether code is in a function and how that function is called) and shell version.

Comment: What I'd suggest is something more like `read -r  -d '' -a running_containers < <(docker ps -aq && printf '\0') || { echo "ERROR: Unable to list running containers" >&2; exit 1; }`, then `if (( ${#running_containers[@]} )); then docker stop "${running_containers[@]}" || exit; docker rm "${running_containers[@]}" || exit; else echo "No running containers found" >&2; fi` -- that way we don't try to invoke `docker stop` or `docker rm` if we detect that there _are no_ running containers, which is the case the OP's original xargs code wasn't handling correctly either.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you for the link. I edited the answer.

Comment: (mind, the above assumes that `docker ps -aq` exits with status 0 if it successfully determines that no running containers exist; I don't run Docker and can't easily test that myself).

Comment: (...as-edited, the above code _also_ checks for failures in `docker ps` and distinguishes them from failures in `docker stop` or `docker rm`, which is itself valuable behavior)